# Preventing copying of structures - with recursive functions

Tags: c++, recursion, copy

a very simplistic (and silly) abstraction of what I'm doing is described below:

```
class A{
private:
    template <typename InIt>
    A foo(InIt begin, InIt end, A& a) {
        // {begin, ind}  is a datastructure containing all "terms" to search for.
        auto iter(sub.begin());
        auto e(sub.end());
        // search trough all elements in original structure.
        do
            if (FUNC) {
                if (++begin != end) {
                    return iter->foo(begin, end, a.append_values(iter));
                    //append_values appends a copy of the element's values at iter
                    //does not copy the sub "trees" of the element at "iter"
                    //it returns a reference to the appended sub "tree"
                } else {
                    return a;
                }
            }
        } while (++iter != e);
        return a;
    }
};
```

Sub is a vector containing objects of class "A" - so effectivelly creating a tree-datastructure. FUNC is a function that must be true for the branch to be "added" to the new tree.

What I'm wondering is: how many copys are "created" if, say, the depth (difference between initial begin, end) is "X". - I'm fearing that for each depth a new copy of "a" is created. This is something I wish to prevent. So should I return by reference? - Or by pointer?

Comment: Won't it only return after it's finished building your datastructure from the element it was given through the iterators?

Comment: Just a note: it seems to me that your iterator type should be named `InputIterator` and not `OutIt`. They are used to read values in the iterated sequence, not to write.

Comment: Well, at the very end it comes to a "return a" statement. However then it walks "back" through the recursive line. And each time it returns the structure again. And as it returns by value I'm at the merci of the compiler to notice that those are all temporaries. But can compilers notice this in recursive functions? @luc, changed - good call :)

Comment: Why do you return `a` in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UncleBens indeed gave the correct question I needed to find a "solution".
I completely "forgot" you can obviously use arguments-by-reference as output too. I don't have to return anything as I edit the original "a", not a copy.